# Reading and iterating through a JSON file

Tags: java, arrays, json, eclipse, parsing

I have a wikidata json file, and I want to read it into a JSONArray so that I could iterate over its items and get each element's properties and values. How can I do it?
I tried iterating over the whole text and parsing each line, but it is too long and complicated for a large file, and I can't get It right that way. Is there more efficient way in Java for reading a JSON file into a JSON array or object so that I could iterate over its items?

Comment: You can use Jackson; depending on how large it is, you read it as a `JsonNode` or you use the streaming API.

Comment: Search about GSON, for example.

https://github.com/google/gson

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A good solution is to use a library for this job. Very good library is the [gson](https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide) . 
You can read the documentation of the library [here](https://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gson/docs/javadocs/com/google/gson/Gson.html).

Answer (score 3):

You can read a huge json file with Gson streaming:

```
JsonReader reader = new JsonReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream, "UTF-8"));
reader.beginArray();
while (reader.hasNext()) {
      // Message message = Gson.fromJson(reader, Message.class);
      // ...
}
reader.endArray();
reader.close();
```

Ref:

1. [Gson streaming](https://sites.google.com/site/gson/streaming)
2. [Gson Streaming to read and write JSON](http://www.mkyong.com/java/gson-streaming-to-read-and-write-json/)

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using https://github.com/jayway/JsonPath to parse it and query the different parts you need. It will construct the list for you.

ie.
$.store.book[?(@.price < 10)]

Answer (score 0):

```
FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(file); 
JSONObject json = (JSONObject) parser.parse(fileReader);
String name = (String) json.get("name"); 
JSONArray departments = (JSONArray) json.get("departments");
```

I think this might help

Comment: I get the execption:
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.json.simple.JSONArray cannot be cast to org.json.simple.JSONObject

Comment: that means you have to directly cast it to JsonArray. 
JSONArray json = (JSONArray) parser.parse(fileReader);